# Codeigniter Form Input Can't Post Form Data

Tags: forms, codeigniter

This seems really silly but I can't get a simple form to work.  Here's my code:

```
<section class="row-fluid"> <!-- search-by-text -->       
     <div class="span8 offset1"> <!-- search by Name input field-->
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
              <?php echo form_open('../main_controller/gsd_search'); ?>
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputLarge">Search by Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input class="input input-lg input-block-level" type="text" id="search_text" placeholder="Enter name then click 'Search'">
              </div>
             <div class="col-sm-2"><!-- search button -->
                <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Search by Name', "class='btn btn-large btn-success'"); ?>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
              </div> <!-- end search button -->         
                </div>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- end input field and button -->
```

When I click on the 'submit' button the URL has

> ?submit=Search+by+Name

attached to it.

Any help with this stupidity would be greatly apreciated.

G.

Comment: u need add to input "name" like <input name="search" ...

Comment: Your suggested fix works. Thank you for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding form in HTML before calling the CodeIgniter form function.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
...
</form>
```

Remove the HTML form tag, since you already generating it using `form_open()`

Comment: Yes, you are correct - this was a silly duplication. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input class="input input-lg input-block-level" type="text" id="search_text" placeholder="Enter name then click 'Search'">
```

Please give name in this input field like

```
<input class="input input-lg input-block-level" type="text"  id="search_text" placeholder="Enter name then click 'Search'" name="search">



<pre>and remove html <form> tag because form_open() create form tag automatically</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try some correction:**

1) Use one of them, either **`<form>..</form>`** or Codeigniter's form helper **`form_open()..form_close()`**. And since you are using CI, use the helper one.

2) There should a **name attribute** in every **input tag** (whether its text, hidden, email, number, etc field).

3) The **action** in **`form_open()`** is **wrong**. It should follow your **base URL** and not the **absolute URL** of your controller.

4) Looking at the URL I can say you are making a **GET request**, but `form_open()` creates a **POST request by default**. Hence I don't why that is happening.

**Modified code:**

**View -**

```
<section class="row-fluid"> <!-- search-by-text -->       
<div class="span8 offset1"> <!-- search by Name input field-->

   <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <?php 
       $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form');
       echo form_open('/main_controller/gsd_search', $attributes); 
    ?>
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputLarge">Search by Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="input input-lg input-block-level" type="text" id="search_text" placeholder="Enter name then click 'Search'" name="search">
          </div>

         <div class="col-sm-2"><!-- search button -->
            <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Search by Name', "class='btn btn-large btn-success'"); ?>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
          </div> <!-- end search button -->         
    </div>

</div> <!-- end input field and button -->
```

**Controller -**

```
class Main_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function gsd_search()
    {
        // your POST data
    }
}
```